# Creating a link with link_to and gsub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to, gsub

I have a body of text being fed into a textarea and if any of the text matches `URI.regexp`, I need to make that link active with a `target: '_blank'` on the `a` tag in the textarea.

Here is my current code. I also tried this with `.match` which would correc

```
def comment_body(text)
  text = auto_link(text)

  text.gsub!(URI.regexp) do |match|
    link_to(match, match, target: '_blank')
  end
end
```

This outputs:

`https://facebook.com">https://facebook.com` in my view

and

`<a href="<a href=" https:="" facebook.com"="" target="_blank">https://facebook.com</a>` in the inspected HTML.

In the [gsub docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) it says that metacharacters will be interpreted literally, which is what I believe is messing me up here.

Any tips on how to properly construct this URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [auto_link](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) gem does exactly what you need.

You can look at its code to see how its using gsub.

Comment: I have a line above, `text = auto_link(text)`. This is already in use. Edited my code above to reflect it

Comment: If you are already using it, simply pass the option to make `target="_blank"` like this: `auto_link(text, :all, :target => "_blank")`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this solution requires setting sanitize to false, which often is not a good idea!

I've found a solution without using auto_link (I'm using Rails 5 too). I know this is an oldish thread but I've spent some time trying to find a solution that would allow the insertion of target="_blank" and found this. Here I'm creating a helper to search text in a text box for links and then add essentially make them linkable in the view.

```
def formatted_comment(comment)
    comment = comment.body

    URI.extract(comment, ['http', 'https']).each do |uri|
        comment = comment.gsub( uri, link_to(uri, uri, target: "_blank"))
    end

    simple_format(comment, {}, class: "comment-body", sanitize: false)
end
```

The key thing here was simple_format kept sanitizing, so it's important to add both {} and sanitize:false.

***Note that setting sanitize to false may bring up other issues like allowing javascript to run in a comment, but this solution will allow the insertion of target="_blank" into a link.

Answer (score -1):

One solution using just a simple `gsub` with back references would be something like this: *(You can certainly modify the regex to meet your needs.)*

```
str = 'here is some text about https://facebook.com and you really http://www.google.com should check it out.'

linked_str = str.gsub( /((http|https):\/\/(www.|)(\w*).(com|net|org))/, 
                         '<a href="\1" target="_blank">\4</a>' )
```

*Example output:*

```
print linked_str
#=> here is some text about <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">facebook</a> and you really <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a> should check it out.
```

Comment: This isn't working. No target="_blank" in the a tag for some reason

Comment: @Zack How is that possible? Paste in exactly what your HTML output is.

Comment: Same as my initial post